# Tangent line to a graph with constant and variable

Tags: calculus

So $f(x) = x+b\sin x$ where $b >0$ and $-2\pi \le x \le 2 \pi$. Find all $x$-coordinates of the points where $y=x+b$ is tangent to the $f(x)$?

I said that $f'(x) = 1+b\cos x$ and $x+b=1+b\cos x$ but that's about as far as I got. PLEASE don't give me the answer, but how do I solve this?

Comment: The points are where the lines cross, $x + b\sin x = x + b$, and where the slope of the tangent equals the slope of the line, $1$. You should have two points within $-2\pi \le x \le 2\pi$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!